# JSON and RSS feeds - difference?

Tags: json, rss

What are the differences between JSON and RSS feeds?

Apart from:

> A JSON feed is in a format that a
>   JavaScript can easily use directly.
>
> Browsers can consume large amount of
>   JSON much more efficiently than they
>   can consume large amount of XML and
>   the gap is widening because the latest
>   versions of the browsers are now
>   providing native, safe support for
>   encoding and decoding JSON.

Comment: JavaScript can't read RSS feeds from remote sites, so you're limited to your own domain. JSON, however, works cross-domain. I think that's the biggest difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JavaScript then you know what a hassle the DOM can be. I would suggest using JSON just because it is easier to program for. I also depends on where you are sending it, whether or not your clients support RSS or JSON.

Other things:

- JSON is easier to debug visually
- Lots of good libraries for JSON in server side languages
- More compact than RSS
- You can define your own api/protocol (RSS is a standard)

Answer (score 0):

JSON's substantially easier to parse. In PHP, for example, it's just `json_decode($json)`.