# how to create an rss feed using JSON?

Tags: xml, json, rss, appcelerator

I like to know how I could create a rss feed with json because right now I got to create one by following the example of kitchen sink

can you guide me please

Comment: Sabrina when you ask questions on here try and be as precise about everything as possible and search here and Google first to see what you find before asking. Please also try and include code whenever you talk about it so in this example you mentioned the KitchenSink. Link to the specific part of the KichtenSink you're asking about so we can give you the best answer possible. If you'd of searched you might have found these first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670511/convert-rss-to-json and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555433/json-and-rss-feeds-difference Both of those could help.

Answer (score 9):

1. Pick a programming language (I'd go with [Perl](http://perl.org/) as I know it and I know the modules that can do this)
2. Pick a JSON parser (I'd use [JSON::Any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::Any))
3. Pick a module that can build an RSS feed (I'd use [XML::RSS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::RSS))
4. Get an HTTP client if you need it ([LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::Simple) will probably do for this)
5. Write some glue code to stick them together.

Comment: thank you for your answer

but as I use Appcelerator's gonna be like the javascript code

I need a small example it would be nice

because I really begins in the Programming and with Appcelerator

Comment: The principle is the same. You need to get the data, parse it, then generate the XML. If you've got problems with one of those steps, I suggest you ask a new and more specific question.

Comment: I just have a little example to see how it looks ready

Answer (score 5):

as far as i know, rss is always XML. You should parse the Json to a correct RSS structure.
check this out:
http://www.xn--schler-dya.net/blog/2008/01/26/converting-json-to-xml-and-xml-to-json/

here is how rss should look:
http://www.landofcode.com/rss-tutorials/rss-structure.php

Comment: thank you

I know how the structure looks like flux rss

I am asked to create an RSS feed using json, but I really do not know what to do over I can not see what is the difference between the two methods

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  [RSS is an XML-based technology](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html).

> RSS is a dialect of XML. All RSS files
>   must conform to the XML 1.0
>   specification, as published on the
>   World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)
>   website.

You might as well ask "how can I write a CSS file with JSON?"

Comment: Funnily enough, json is closer is syntax to css than xml will ever be :)

Answer (score 0):

Using titanium if you want to build and XML like the one in the KitcheSink example you need to use XML. If you have JSON you could parse it yourself or use the `Ti.Yahoo.yql` to conver the JSON to XML then do the feed the same as the KitchenSink example.

[Ti.Yahoo.yql](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Yahoo-module)

Comment: thank you for all that information but meToi data in an xml file and am asked to code with json

Comment: you can still use `Ti.Yahoo.yql` to convert from XML to JSON then.

Answer (score 0):

RSS is based on XML. You cannot create one using JSON

Comment: I did not know it, yet I was given a little code that I have not tested yet